# OpenLiberty startup frozen when ran tests agaist Arquillian liberty-managed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

The sample project is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter).

Openliberty 20.0.0.1
AdaptOpenJDK 8

The configuration for arquillian liberty-managed profile.

```xml
 <profile>
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-liberty-managed -->
            <id>arq-liberty-managed</id>
            <properties>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.openliberty.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-liberty-managed</artifactId>
                    <version>${arquillian-liberty.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>io.openliberty</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>openliberty-runtime</artifactId>
                                            <version>${liberty.runtime.version}</version>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--<environmentVariables>
                                <WLP_HOME>${project.build.directory}/wlp</WLP_HOME>
                            </environmentVariables>-->
                            <systemProperties>
                                <arquillian.launch>liberty-managed</arquillian.launch>
                            </systemProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

And the *arquillian.xml* file content:

```xml
    <container qualifier="liberty-managed">
        <configuration>
            <property name="wlpHome">target/wlp/</property>
            <property name="serverName">defaultServer</property>
            <property name="httpPort">9080</property>
            <property name="serverStartTimeout">300</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
```

When running the test via the following command:

```sh
mvn clean verify -Parq-liberty-managed
```

And got the info from the console. The Github Actions build log can be found [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter/runs/431447710).

```sh
087 seconds.
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 311.064 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.it.GreetingResourceTest
[ERROR] com.example.it.GreetingResourceTest  Time elapsed: 311.05 s  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Unable to retrieve connector address for localConnector of started VM

[INFO] Running com.example.it.GreetingServiceTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.03 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.it.GreetingServiceTest
[ERROR] com.example.it.GreetingServiceTest  Time elapsed: 0.018 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Arquillian initialization has already been attempted, but failed. See previous exceptions for cause
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Unable to retrieve connector address for localConnector of started VM

[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0055I: Server shutdown requested on Friday, February 7, 2020 at 4:44 PM. The server defaultServer is shutting down.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE1100I: Waiting for up to 30 seconds for the server to quiesce.
[INFO    ] CWWKE1101I: Server quiesce complete.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0036I: The server defaultServer stopped after 5 minutes, 12.017 seconds.
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dcom.ibm.ws.logging.console.log.level=INFO
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: The issue may be this error `Unable to retrieve connector address for localConnector of started VM` which indicates you need to enable the `localConnector-1.0` feature in your server.xml?

Comment: @AndyGuibert After read some codes of `liberty-managed`, I got the solution. The problem is liberty-managed does not read server.xml from *src/main/liberty* (like what maven plugin do) or test classpath, only read the file from **server config** folder. But there is **no doc to explain this**. I added  some issues about  these, but all are closed without any positive repsonse.

Comment: The server.xml must exist in the server directory in order for its configuration to be read by the runtime. The Arquillian Liberty managed container assumes, for the most part, that the server configuration is already present and correct beforehand in order to properly manage the lifecycle. I'm not sure what configuration you would want in the `arquillian-liberty-managed` documentation, as the standard location of the server.xml is set by the Liberty runtime and not by the `arquillian-liberty-managed` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the codes of **liberty-managed**, I found the reason. The liberty-managed does not read *server.xml* from either *src/main/liberty/config*(like what liberty maven plugin does) or the test classpath. It only read the server.xml file from the server config folder aka *<wlp>/usr/servers/<servername>*.

But the is **no doc and example to explain this** in the liberty arquillian project.

Create a liberty-managed specific folder under */src/test/*, named *arq-liberty-managed*, move *server.xml*, *arquillian.xml*(add a copy of it) into it.

In my **arq-liberty-managed** profile, add test-resource config.

```xml
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/arq-liberty-managed</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>server.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/arq-liberty-managed</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>server.xml</include>
            </includes>
            <targetPath>
                ${project.build.directory}/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer
            </targetPath>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
...
```